# ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1), even with supplied argument

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an "attack" method that for some reason, returns `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)`, even though I provide an argument. The call is a.attack(b) where both a and b are instances of the UnitInstance class

This is my class and the attack method is at the botton - any suggestions are much appreciated!

EDIT: Also, this is a model within a rails application, but it doesn't need to connect with he DB

```
class UnitInstance
    attr_accessor :name, :health, :current_health, :attack, :defence, 
    :initiative, :amount, :conditions

    def initialize(unit_id, amount)
        unit = Unit.find(unit_id)
        @name = unit.name
        @health = unit.health
        @current_health = unit.health
        @attack = unit.attack
        @defence = unit.defence
        @initiative = unit.initiative
        @amount = amount
        @conditions = []
    end

    def strength
        amount * attack
    end

    def dead?
        health <= 0 and amount <= 0
    end

    def find_target(enemies)

    end

    def decrease_health(_amount)
        hp = health * (self.amount - 1) + current_health
        hp -= _amount
        self.amount = hp / health + 1
        if hp % health == 0         
            self.amount -= 1
            self.current_health = 5
        else
            self.current_health = hp % health
        end
    end

    def attack(target)
        target.decrease_health(strength)
        decrease_health(target.defence) unless target.dead?     
        "#{name.titleize} attacked #{target.name.titleize} for #{attack} damage,"
    end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a method named `attack` with one argument which you call by `a.attack(b)`

```
def attack(target)
  target.decrease_health(strength) ## <<-- Notice this
  decrease_health(target.defence) unless target.dead?     
  "#{name.titleize} attacked #{target.name.titleize} for #{attack} damage,"
end
```

You are invoking `strength` method inside `attack` and within `strength`

```
def strength
  amount * attack  ## << -- No arguments here
end
```

You are getting error from `strength` method where you are invoking `attack` without any arguments.

`@amount` and `@attack` are **instance variables** for which you have defined getter and setter methods using `attr_accessor`. 
So, for `@attack` you now have two methods, `attack` and `attack=`.

Remember that

> There may be only one method with given name in Ruby class. If several
>   methods with the same name defined in the class - the latest
>   overwrites previous definitions.

So, when you define `attack(target)` with argument the accessor method `attack` is overwritten. Now, you are left with only two methods `attack(target)` and `attack=`

Comment: amount and attack are instance variables

Comment: `@amount` and `@attack` are instance variable. `amount` and `attack` are methods.